# escaping double quotes and percent signs (%) in cron

Tags: cron

The following command works from prompt but not from crontab.

```bash
grep abc /var/log/messages | grep "`date '+%B %d'`" | mail -s"abc log of `hostname`" s.o+`hostname`@gmail.com
```

I need to add it to daily cron.

Comment: Your example is amazing, the % is surrounded by double, simple and back quotes. Leaving no hope that quote escaping could work.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You have to escape the `%` signs. They have a special meaning in crontabs:

```
man (5) crontab:

Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), 
will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the 
first % will be sent to the command as standard input.
```

Comment: Well I just did run into this. I was using `date +%F` and was getting nowhere

Comment: Does this syntax have any useful use? With `SHELL=/bin/bash`, I can always rewrite `cat %Hello world` as `cat <<<'Hello world'`. I do not see the need for special syntax.

Comment: @Witiko If the "special syntax" you're asking about is the backslash to escape percent, then the OP's own question is an example where it's needed: command arguments that require percent, notably the date program, which would be quite popular in a crontab command.  If you're actually asking why cron has this gotcha in the first place: ie: substitutes linefeed in place of percent, then I guess it's so you can supply, on a single line that crontab requires, a "command" that consist of two or more subsidiary commands.

Comment: The latter. And, as I mentioned, one can do the same with bash. No need to litter the syntax of Cron.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would suggest that you create a script file in /usr/local/bin (or ~/bin or whatever is appropriate) and call that from cron.  It's easier to test and edit.

Comment: In my experience, it is much easier to maintain 50 lines in a crontab than it is to maintain 50 tiny files. You will want to turn longer scripts into script files for sure, but doing so for one-liners may be an overkill.