# Command will run in shell but throws unexpected EOF error in cron

Tags: centos, backup, cron

I am trying to run the following in cron to back up a server every morning at 4am:

```
0 4 * * * dump -0uan -f - / | gzip -2 | ssh -c blowfish user@server dd of=/backups/`hostname`_`date '+%m-%d-%Y_%k%M%S'`.dump.gz
```

Running the command on it's own from the shell works fine. Usually when this happens the problem is due to paths, so I tried adding full paths in cron:

```
0 4 * * * /sbin/dump -0uan -f - / | /usr/bin/gzip -2 | /usr/bin/ssh -c blowfish user@server /bin/dd of=/backups/`hostname`_`date '+%m-%d-%Y_%k%M%S'`.dump.gz
```

and still no luck. I checked the system log and saw this:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The same error occurs with and without paths specified. Should be a pretty simple command. Is cron executing this differently than it is written?

Comment: You should escape percent sign.
I've found answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/274475/escaping-double-quotes-and-percent-signs-in-cron

Comment: Doh! That was it. Guess I never had to use % signs in a command directly in cron before. Make it an answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the percent sign, or put that whole line in a script and trigger that instead.